# Try to set really long password but passwd keeps freezing

Tags: macos, terminal, root, passwd

I have a password that is about 5000 characters long. I am trying to use `passwd` to set the password but it keeps hanging on the `New password:` prompt once it hit enter. Is this just a slow execution time issue or has it completely crashed.

Comment: How long did you take to type that PassWord ?? How will you type the PassWord the next time when you want to log in ??

Comment: tl;dr: don't do that

Comment: I don't know macOS at all, but if your macOS generates hashes of a certain length then at some point expanding a password by 1 character is unlikely to make it more secure, because the probability of collision with some shorter password rises. In other words: if you managed to set this 5000-character password, it would be almost certain there exists a shorter password that allows access. E.g. SHA-512 [can be encoded as 88 characters of base64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18236139/10765659), so I expect that exceeding about this number of printable characters in a password gives me no gain.

Answer (score 5):

The character limit on passwords is 250.

It doesn't actually say so on the macOS password hints page, but Google helpfully includes it when searched.

> [image]

[Apple KB - Tips for creating secure passwords on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp1088/mac)

It's well-known across platforms, that ultra-long passwords can cause issues. Most especially on web & application structures that fail to warn when the limit is exceeded. This can result in the correct password failing. Not a great issue on a web form with an 'I forgot' button, much bigger deal on an encrypted disk.

Comment: I would also note that a 256 character password with nothing but the characters "1" and "0" is, literally, a 256 bit password, having a keyspace of 2^256.  A 128 bit password with nothing but 1's and 0's is a keyspace of 2^128; this is equivalent to any other 128 bit security mechanism available.
A 128 character password of nothing but lower case letters plus numbers is a keyspace of 36^128, or 1.6E199, or 2^661 - more than enough for anything in the forseeable future.